# Unable to convert base64 string to pdf

Tags: java, pdf-writer

```
    Document document = new Document();

    String b64Image = medikmResourceRequest.getResourceImage();
    String fileName = resourceDir+"/"+medikmResourceRequest.getPhysicianId()+"/"+medikmResourceRequest.getName()+" "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".pdf";

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)));
    document.open();

    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(b64Image.getBytes());

    document.add(Image.getInstance(decoded));
    document.close();
```

Above code is not working properly for large images, they are getting cropped but its working fine for small image.

Please suggest.

Comment: try to set the resolution before converting to pdf doc, its obvious if you try to write large size image it will not fit the doc, else you will have to set the page layout, may be portrait or landscape.

Comment: Thank you for answer can you tell how can i set the size ...

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `medikmResourceRequest.getResourceImage()` and `b64Image.getBytes()`.

Your program should NOT transfer `byte[]`(image data) via String. 
When JVM convert `byte[]` to String, if the byte data cannot mapping to char of String's charset.
It will be replace to `?`. The `byte[]` returned by `b64Image.getByte()` is differnet than original data and cause your image broken.

Comment: Thank you for answer my problem is getting solved by using    `Rectangle one = new Rectangle(1500,1100);                                                                 document.setPageSize(one);`